# Привязать нажатие Enter в текстовом поле к клику по кнопке

Tags: java

Есть текстовое поле `TextBox text`
и есть кнопка `Button button` в которой уже есть обработчик события `OnClick`

```
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
           // Код...    
        }
});
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при вводе текста в text при нажатии клавиши Enter
сработал обработчик `onClick` button-а ?
Ну как бы сказать, что Enter при вводе текста и клик на button - это одно и то же?

Comment: eventHandler использовать по-моему надо. И в функции `e.getKey() == VK.ENTER`

Comment: Да, у меня обработчик нажатия Enter-а уже есть. Мне бы как то "скормить" в if-е вызов обработчика клика по кнопке

Answer (score 1):

Создайте метод, выполняющий независимый функционал из обработчика. Поместите вызов метода в обработчики событий для клика и для  нажатия кнопки Enter.
Если требуется, передавайте в метод параметры.

Comment: Дело в том, что я уже думал об этом. Слишком много всего передавать придется.. Можно ли как то ещё?

Comment: @Vard32 добавьте код в вопрос, посмотрю что там и как можно сделать

Comment: Да в принципе DimXenon сказал правильный вариант, я просто думал что это как то элегантно можно сделать, привязав действие одного контрола к другому. Такая фича была вроде бы в Delphi. Всё делалось на уровне свойств в визуальном редакторе.

Comment: Иногда приходится выбирать между ленивым и правильным решением, по себе знаю. Лучше раз переделать архитектуру приложения и уже удобно его расширять, чем рыть самому себе яму с кольями на дне, каждый раз приспосабливаясь под сложившуюся архитектуру (не оптимальную и не гибкую), вместо того, чтобы приспособить архитектуру под свои нужды.

Comment: Полностью согласен.

Comment: На случай, если вариантов других не будет - просто создайте экземпляр MouseEvent (или нужного Event'а) и используйте на целевом объекте метод fireEvent([имя созданного экземпляра MouseEvent]) в теле хендлера другого события (или где угодно ещё).